# 画面遷移時に管理Beanにデータを設定する方法

Tags: java, java-ee

ボタンを押下すると、BeanAのnextPage()が起動し、BeanB管理ページに遷移します。nextPage()実行時にBeanBの変数に値を設定し、BeanBで使用したいのですが方法はありますでしょうか。

・BeanA(a.xhtmlを管理)

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BeanA{

    public String nextPage(){
        //ここでBeanBのlist及び@Entityを付与したentityにデータを設定したい。
        return "b.xhtml";
    }
}
```

・BeanB(b.xhtmlを管理)

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BeanB{
    private List<CustomClass> list;
    private CustomEntity entity;
    // コンストラクタ（省略）
　　// アクセサメソッド（省略）
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewScopedのBeanからViewScopedのBeanを直接呼ぶことはできません。
ですので、BeanBに直接値を設定するのではなく、RequestScopedを付けたValueObjectを用意して、そちらを参照するようにしてはどうでしょうか。

ValueObject:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ValueObject
{
    private List<CustomClass> list;
    private CustomEntity entity;
}
```

BeanA:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BeanA
{    

    @Inject
    private ValueObject valueObject;

    public String nextPage()
    {
        valueObject.setList(...);   // ValueObjectに設定
        valueObject.setEntity(...); // ValueObjectに設定
        return "b.xhtml";
    }
}
```

BeanB:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BeanB
{
    @Inject
    private ValueObject valueObject;
}
```

このようにすれば、BeanBが呼ばれた時点で、ValueObjectにはBeanAで設定した値が設定されているので、好きなように参照することができます。

Comment: 希望していた通りのことができました。ありがとうございます。しかし、気になるのはViewScopedのBeanからViewScopedのBeanを直接呼ぶことができないということです。例えばBBeanがCDI管理Beanでしたら@Injectすることはできないのでしょうか？また、SessionScopedなどだったら良いのでしょうか？

Comment: Beanのスコープによるライフサイクルの問題です。ViewScopedは画面が表示されている間だけ有効、つまり、BeanAにBeanBをInjectすることはできますが、それはb.xhtmlを開いた際にインスタンス化されるBeanBとは異なるインスタンスになってしまいます。SessionScopedであれば、セッションが有効な間はインスタンスが維持されるのでOKということになります。

Comment: b.xhtmlを読み込んだ時はBeanAがインスタンス化したBeanBは破棄されて。BeanBがまた新たにインスタンス生成されるんですね。
わかりやすい解説ありがとうございました。